# submitting the div content in a form

Tags: javascript, html

submitting the div content in a form. I retrieved database records in a div and now wants to insert the content of the div into database. how can I achieve that.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#SignupForm").on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

url: "insert.php",


            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#targetLayer").html(data);
$('#loader').hide();
$('#alerts').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
</script>


<form>
<div id="targetLayer"></div>
<input type=text id="targetLayer" name="targetLayer">
<input submit>
</form>
```

Comment: What is in your div that you want to submit?

Comment: First of all, I don't see any element with #SignupForm (which you refer to in your code). After that you have there targetLayer id twice, id should be unique.

Comment: @ aj_r. its list of names

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend submitting div content to your database. A malicious user could put whatever they want in the div and submit it. It also makes your user interface very tightly coupled with your page logic and may involve a lot of string parsing that could otherwise be avoided.

I saw in your comment that the div will have a list of names, I would look into alternate ways of getting this list that don't involve placing it in your HTML.

If this is really what you want to do. Assuming the div is a child of your `#SignupForm` element, I would put the div content retrieval method in your submit event handler like so:

```
$("#SignupForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //
        //Get the div content
        //Replace #idofdiv with the selector for your div
        var divContent = $('#idofdiv',this).text()
        //
        //Put it in the form data
        //Change listOfNames to the name that you want the data to be posted as
        var formData = new FormData(this)
        formData.append("listOfNames", divContent)
        //
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  formData, //Change so it gets the right form data
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#targetLayer").html(data);
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#alerts').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but what variable do I pass in a form to submit it in a database

Comment: In my above example you would be able to get the form data from the `$_POST` variable in PHP. To get the contents of the div you would get the "listOfNames" index of the $_POST variable like so:  `$_POST['listOfNames']`.